# Kusto: union of intermediate result produced by expensive calculation

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have an expensive query which requires a lot of CPU & Memory to produce the result. However, the result data set contains only a limited number of rows.

```
let result = expensive_function()
    | summarize A=xxx, B=xxx by X, Y, Z;
```

I want to append another row further summarized from the result. For example, omit the `Z` column in the summarize keys, and set `Z="ALL"` for the result row.

```
result
| union (
    result
    | summarize A=XXX, B=XXX by X, Y
    | extend Z="ALL"
)
```

When this is executed, it seems Kusto will expand and execute the `expensive_function()` in parallel in the `union` operator, which results in twice CPU and Memory consumption.

I tried to add `hint.concurrency=1` to the `union` operator, this will reduce the peak memory to be same as a single result query, however, the execution time will be doubled.

Can we give a hint to Kusto that we need to freeze the intermediate result, and all the followed query should operate on the frozen intermediate result rather than calculating all from source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the materialize() function:

```
let result = materialize(expensive_function()
    | summarize A=xxx, B=xxx by X, Y, Z);
result
| union (
    result
    | summarize A=XXX, B=XXX by X, Y
    | extend Z="ALL"
)
```